# Closing bootstrap modal using ESC

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using 2 modals, 1st one contains a form and 2nd shows up when an error occurs in the form. 2nd modal contains only text with error message.

My problem is that when 2nd modal show up and I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the first one (with the form) will close instead on the 2nd one.

Is there any way how to focus the 2nd modal when it shows up?

[image]

This is how it looks like, now if I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the 1st one would close, but I want to close the 2nd one first.

**UPDATE**

Once I click somewhere on the 2nd modal, it works perfectly. I just need to select/focus it automatically

Comment: Don't open many modals, we are not on Windows 3.1 anymore.

Comment: @moonwave99 why not?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with how the `keyup` event is being bound.

You can add the `tabindex` *attribute* to your modal to get around this issue:

```
 tabindex="-1"
```

So your full code should look like this:

```
<a href="#my-modal" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</a>

<div class='modal fade hide' id='my-modal' tabindex='-1'>
<div class='modal-body'>
<div>Test</div>
</div>
```

For more info you can view the discussion on this issue on github:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4663

Comment: see this like you want under Stackable title http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Comment: it is working there, but still doesn't work for me that's weird

Comment: use jsfiddle just add in External Resources  the cdn of twitter-bootstrap.js

Comment: @feri U might have somewhere in your code, disabled keyboard, like,

$('#deleteConfirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })

          .on('click', '#delete-btn', function () {
});

Comment: Thanks it really helpfull. I was triend many ways of javascript but I dont no why those doesn't worket but this one tabindex worked for me.