# Bootstrap modal not closing on "esc"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a regular Bootstrap 3 modal window:

```
<div id="test_modal" class="modal animated fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="true" tabindex="-1">
```

But on keyboard <kbd>ESC</kbd> only works **after** clicked once inside the modal. Just hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> lets the cursor disappear, only coming back on "click".

Anyone can explain that to me and advise?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a focus problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing bootstrap modal using ESC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790557/closing-bootstrap-modal-using-esc)

Comment: do you have `tabindex="-1"` on your modal?

Comment: yes, see the code in my question, tabindex="-1" is in there. I checked the other posts on stackoverflow and googled and tried what I found was suggested with no success. Hence my post here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Per Bootstrap 3 Modal docs:

> Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use some custom JavaScript:
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
>   $('#myInput').focus()
> })
> ```